# how to get gradlew script to pull most latest version

Tags: gradle

My gradlew script which I am not sure where it came from is pulling 1.3 gradle instead of the latest which we would like to be using.  How to make it so it pulls the latest every time?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Gradle wrapper only supports fixed versions at this time.

Comment: oh, in that case, where do I set the fixed version?  I didn't see a property file or anything. thanks,

Comment: Either you declare a `Wrapper` task with the desired version and regenerate the wrapper, or you edit the URL in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`.